# Key expected String but value was a java.lang.Integer(Arrayadapter values)

Tags: java, android

Im trying to send values from one class to the other and display it. However th values wont display, and im getting a blank window. It doesnt show any red errors, but in the logcat you can find a line of text that says: Key playerList expected String but value was a java.lang.Integer. So i guess for some reason im getting ints instead of strings. I dont know why that happens, though i have felling that i know where is the problem.

So this is my first Activity where a user inputs strings and ads the to the listview(adapter).

```
     public class ZaidejaiActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    public Button mBtnIstrinti;
    public Button mBtnPrideti;
    public Button mBtnPradeti;
    public EditText mYrasytiVarda;
    public ListView mZaidejai;

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zaidejai);
        mBtnPrideti = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pridėtiBtn);
        mBtnPrideti.setOnClickListener(this);
        mYrasytiVarda = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.VardoYrasymoBtn);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);

        // set the mZaidejai variable to your list in the xml

        mZaidejai=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.sarašas);
        mZaidejai.setAdapter(adapter); 
        mZaidejai.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

             // remove item from List.



            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                    list.remove(position);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ZaidejaiActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Delete?");
                builder.setTitle("Confirm Action");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        //checked.clear();
                    });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                builder.create();
                builder.show();
            }
        });
        mBtnPradeti = (Button)findViewById(R.id.žaistiBtn);
        mBtnPradeti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    // count items
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    String obj = adapter.getItem(i);
                    // send items to other activity
                    Intent pradetiZaidima = new Intent(v.getContext(), ZaidimasActivity.class);
                    pradetiZaidima.putExtra("playerList", adapter.getPosition(obj));
                    startActivity(pradetiZaidima);
                }
            }
        });

    };


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String input = mYrasytiVarda.getText().toString();
        if(input.length() > 0)
        {
            // add string to the adapter, not the listview
            adapter.add(input);

            // no need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); as it is done by the adapter.add() method
        }else{
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Klaida:");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Blogai yrašytas vardas");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
// here you can add functions
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

In this activity I want to display the inputs.:

public class ZaidimasActivity extends ZaidejaiActivity {

```
public TextView mZaidejas;
public TextView mKlausimas;
public Button mKitasKlausimas;

ArrayList<String> listas;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zaidimas);

    Bundle recdData = getIntent().getExtras();
    String myVal = recdData.getString("playerList");


    //listas = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("playerList");


    mZaidejas = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ZaidejoVardas);
    mZaidejas.setText(myVal);

}
```

I have a felling that the wrong part of the code is where I am sending items to the other activity. the `pradetiZaidima.putExtra("playerList", adapter.getPosition(obj));`I think the getposition part hasto be changed with something else but everything i dried just shows as red. I thought the best solution was to use getList but it is red too. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is very simple:

When you start the intent you are calling `pradetiZaidima.putExtra("playerList", adapter.getPosition(obj));` which returns the position of `obj` in the adapter (an `Integer`).

Then in `String myVal = recdData.getString("playerList");` you are expecting to receive a `String`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
pradetiZaidima.putExtra("playerList", adapter.getPosition(obj));
```

with

```
pradetiZaidima.putExtra("playerList", obj);
```

Since in the next activity you are looking for the string value with `readData.getString("playerList");`